# Partition function of 2D Ising model on a squared lattice in the canonical ensemble in the low temperature limit

Tags: ising-model, partition-function, lattice-model

I'm currently working through David Tong's script on statistical mechanics (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/sp.pdf) and came across something that I don't quite understand (page 166).

After determining the first lower energy states we end up with the following partition function

$$Z = 2e^{2N\beta J}\left(1+Ne^{-8\beta J} + 2Ne^{-12\beta J} + \frac{1}{2}(N^2+9N)e^{-16\beta J} + \dots\right)$$

I have some difficulties understanding the next step of the script where we determine $\ln Z$.
For some reason we end up with

$$\ln Z=\ln2 + 2N\beta J + Ne^{-8\beta J} + 2Ne^{-12\beta J} + \frac{9}{2}Ne^{-16\beta J} + \dots$$

where the $N^2$ term has "canceled out".
I know that we can approximate $\ln 1+x \approx x$ but that still does not explain why the $N^2$ term disappears.

Am I overlooking something important?

Comment: You cannot ignore the higher-order terms in the expansion of the logarithm: it is them that will lead to the cancellation of the $N^2$ term (and of all terms that are not proportional to $N$). Notice for example that, since $\ln(1+x) = x - \frac12 x^2 + \dots$, you will get a term $-\tfrac12 (N e^{-8\beta J})^2$ which will cancel the term proportional to $N^2$ that you wrote. This can be generalized to all terms, but the proof is not trivial.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!